# How to hide a component without unmounting it?

Tags: layout, react-native

I've got a list component that I would like to keep in the DOM whenever it's not needed so that the scroll position is not lost.

I've tried setting the style to `{display: 'none'}` but this unmounts the component. I've also tried setting `{ flex: 0.0001 }` which kind of works but it feels like a hack (which they might optimise to "0" later on) and it creates layout glitches when the component is shown/hidden.

Any idea what would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: height = 0 and width = 0 , does this work ?

Comment: {display: 'none'} does not unmount the component. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 18):

I have found that in recent React Native the approach with:

```
{ display: 'none' }
```

Do the works fine for me, my Tab component switches layouts without unmounting it's contents.

Tested on: `RN 0.58.1, iPhone X 12.1`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the component to stay mounted but not take up any space or render anything? What if you just pass a `hide` property to the component which will just return an empty view in the render if it's true.

Comment: Yes, to stay mounted while being invisible. I've tried returning null as well, but this would be the equivalent of unmounting the component (since the list would still be unloaded).

Comment: You need the list from inside the component?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style={{visibility: this.state.hidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible'}}>
    content
</div>
```