# Google Maps JS - Create a new div holding an existing global map object in a React SPA

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3

How can I create a new div that holds an existing global Google Maps JS map object in my React single-page app?

I create a map object at the root level of my app, and now I want to display it in different pages on my website. It's easy to send the map object to child components (I use React Context). But I still haven't found a way to create, in the React JSX of my child components, a div that holds the map.

When the Google script (and the callback Initmap function) is run, it seems to kind of "link" the new map object to a unique div (it links it to an existing div with the matching id, otherwise it creates a new div).

But if this div is later removed from the DOM (which happens all the time in a SPA), it seems impossible to create a new div linked with this existing map. I've tried all kinds of methods (sending the ref to the child, copy-paste the initial div...) but once the initial div has disappeared from the DOM, there seems to be nothing to do to display the map.

Any suggestion is welcome ! I've been stuck on this issue for days, and for the very first time I can't find a workaround...

Tell me if additional information is needed (such as code), but I think the question is self-explanatory and the issue is not directly linked to my code.

Comment: Have you tried hiding the component / div like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45445630/18422887